# Blocked myself from server with form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, forms

So I've been working on something for a client involving a very simple form that generates a url and the resultant page outputs a table. The form is explicitly set to `method="POST"` and `action=""`, with JS handling the url like so: `onsubmit="this.action='{site_url}/entries/'+this.survey.value+'/'+this.job_number.value;"`

The form works fine, but now after several dozen submissions (mostly re-submissions of the same form), the server has blocked my IP (via CSF).

What has caused this and how can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: I think you need to ask whoever's in control of the server, as it's apparently been programmed or configured to do it for whatever reason. There's no general "servers block you after X or Y" rule.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, (maybe if you posted the code). But what I would tell you is, why dont you just use method="GET" and forget about javascript?

Comment: @NathanParker You'd think that would have been the obvious approach, but I put this in and it worked so I just moved on.

Comment: @NathanParker Actually I remember why I didn't use GET. That would create url parameters and I wanted to create url segments that can easily be parsed by the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the service you are using is either cooperating with you or not. If he/she is cooperating with you, then you should ask them about the cause of this issue. I am sure they will give you just the information you need to know about their server, so you will not encounter the issue again as long as you follow their policies. If they are not cooperating with you, well, then this is certainly an unlucky event, probably without a solution.